# Update database from form with several joins

Tags: php

I have a group with a leader who is updating the members in the group. A member with a rolesID of 11 is pending and I want to change their rolesID depending on the option selected in the dropdown.

Here's the form:

```
<form action='updatePendingMembers.php' method='post' onsubmit='return checkForm()'>
    <?php
    $pendingMembers = "SELECT m.id, concat(fname, ' ', lname) as mName, email, m.rolesID FROM member m join member_to_groups on m.id = member_to_groups.memberID left join groups on member_to_groups.groupsID = groups.id WHERE m.rolesID = 11 AND groups.memberID = " . $_SESSION['siteMemberId'];
    $rsPendingMembers = mysql_query($pendingMembers);
    //if(!$rsPendingMembers)
        //echo 'the query is: ' . $pendingMembers . '<br/>and the error: ' . mysql_error();
    while($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsPendingMembers)){
    ?>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" class="Sub_Header">Pending Group members</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3"><span class="Maintext"><?php echo $get_row['mName']?></span>
    <select name="rolesID" class="lowermenu" id="rolesID">
        <option value="12">Accept</option>
        <option value="11">Decline</option>
    </select>
      <a href="mailto:<?php echo $get_row['email']?>"><span class="lowermenu">send pending member message</span></a></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    <td><span class="Sub_Header">
        <input name="update_pending_member_button" type="submit" id="update_pending_member_button" value="Update Member">
      </span></td>
      </form>
```

Here's the updatePendingMembers.php file so far:

```
<?php
session_start();
include("global.php");
$myQuery1 = "UPDATE member SET rolesID = " .  mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['rolesID']) WHERE id = ;
$rs1 = mysql_query($myQuery1);
?>
```

How do I set the id equal to the member who was selected and in that particular group? Thanks.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [**prepared statements**](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 1):

Use array like names for form elemnts:

```
<select name="rolesID[<?php echo $get_row['id']; ?>]" class="lowermenu" id="rolesID">
    <option value="12">Accept</option>
    <option value="11">Decline</option>
</select>
```

Your `$_POST` data will look like that:

```
$_POST['rolesID'] = array(
   '1' => '11',
   '2' => '12'
);
```

You can iterate through it and update every record:

```
foreach ($_POST['rolesID'] as $id => $role) {
    $id = (int)$id;
    $role = (int)$role;
    $sql = "UPDATE member SET roleID = {$role} WHERE id = {$id}";
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I implemented your suggestion. When I echo the query it shows it exactly as it should be:
"the query is: UPDATE member SET rolesID = 12 WHERE id = 2"
...but it's not updating it in the databse. Why is that?

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you so much!

Comment: If a member is declined, they need to be removed from members_to_groups. How do I do that?